# How can I subtract only the values in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe consists of a Column "timeStamp". I'm trying to obtain the difference between two values of two set of data frames.  I use the following piece of code for it (see code). My question: How can I keep the date the same and only subtract the values?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` is a nice approach as [SwaggaTing suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914779). Alternatively, you can set your date as the index:

```
a.set_index('date')['values_TProducing'] - b.set_index('date')['values_AProducing']
```

Comment: this is NEAT @busybear!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dates are unique, you can join the dataframes on the date column and then subtract:

```
merged = a.merge(b, on='date')
merged['diff'] = merged['values_AProducing'] - merged['values_TProducing']
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the dates line up as they do in your example:

```
x = a.copy().drop('values_TProducing', 1)
x['values'] = a['values_TProducing'] - b['values_AProducing']
```